# php <a href> how to pass value to another page when click the href? and how to retrieve the value from another page?

Tags: php, html, sql

How do I pass the value with `a href` when click href link and go next page? Beside that, on the next page how I retrieve the value?

My code:

```
                <?php

            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT movie.image, movie.name, movie.id
                                FROM movie 
                                INNER JOIN movie_genre 
                                ON movie.id = movie_genre.movie_id 
                                INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = movie_genre.genre_id
                                INNER JOIN movie_date ON movie_date.movie_id = movie.id
                                ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 6";

            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
                    echo '<label class="label1">' . $row->name . '</label><br><br>';
                    echo '<a href="#"><img src="' . $row->image . '" class="poster"></a>';
                    echo '<div class = "section3"><a href="synopsis.php?id="' . $row->id . '" >asd</a>&nbsp &nbsp <a href="">Buy Now</a>';
                }
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use GET?

Comment: Can giv me reference? if not inside form tag still can use GET?

Comment: Currently it looks like you are passing an id on the synopsis link.  You should be able to retrieve that at your destination.

Comment: @Progrock that right, so I passed it right? my code is correct?

Comment: If your link looks something like: `synopsis.php?id=23`, then that should be okay.  Your image however looks to be missing a link.

Comment: @Progrock Yup, i got it, cause I want pass the id value, so the image just left it. :) thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first page

```
echo '<a href="next_page.php?next_id='. $row->id.'"><img src="' . $row->image . '" class="poster"></a>';
```

to retrieve

```
$_GET['next_id'];
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it! You solution can too

Answer (score 1):

You can use _GET of php for this, however there are many methods exist.

First set value in href url as below :

```
<a href="?key=my_value" .....
```

Then you can acces value in target php as below:

```
<?php echo  $_GET['key'];//displays my_value
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it! You solution can !

Comment: youre welcome :) you can check the solution you want as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

This may help:
[PHP GET method in <a href>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683923/php-get-method-in-a-href)

You simply add your data to the URL in your href and retrieve it on the next page by using the GET Method.

For example in your `echo a href`:

```
echo '<a href="movie.php?id="' . $row->id .'"><img src="' . $row->image . '" class="poster"></a>';
```

And then in movie.php you would use

```
$_GET['id'];
```

To fetch the selected movie.

Answer (score 0):

Using $_GET['id'] you will get value pass from URL

Comment: I got it, appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your id is an integer.

```
<?php

$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

If you have a query parameter of id, the above will filter and convert the input string into an integer.  If it doesn't look like one it will assign `false` to `$id`.

Note if no value is passed `$id` will be `null`.  So in further code you may need to additionally test:

```
<?php
if(is_int($id)) {
    // Do something.
}
```